# How to rewrite a php script to JavaScript

Tags: php, sql, node.js

I have an express server running using nodejs, and I'm using SQL syntax to query data from my MYSQL database.

The query is to get all members under the current user ID and also get members under it's children and so on, to get a genealogy tree. I'm trying to query a genealogy tree for a user.

I have a PHP script for the query, which worked fine

This is the PHP script:

```
$memory = $_GET['memory'];  
echo '<div style="background:#ccc;display:flex;width:50px;height:50px;justify- 
content:center;align-items:center;border-radius:50%;">'.$memory.'</div>';
$transend = array($memory);
$step = 1;
for ($i=0; $i < $step; $i++) {
    $under = $transend[$i];
    $get = $con->query("SELECT * FROM multilevel WHERE `under`='$under'");
    $cnt = $get->num_rows;
    if ($cnt>0) {
        for ($g=0; $g < $cnt; $g++) {
            $fet = $get->fetch_object();
            $id = $fet->id;
            $position = $fet->position;
            array_push($transend, $id);
            $step = $step*2;
            echo '<div style="background:#ccc;display:flex;width:50px;height:50px;justify-content:center;align-items:center;border-radius:50%;">'.$id.'-'.$position.'</div>';
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

I am trying to rewrite it using SQL syntax in node. This is my nodejs code:

A Tree Constructor

```
const Tree = function (binary) {
 this.position = binary.position;
 this.level = binary.level;
 this.user_id = binary.user_id;
 this.under_user_id = binary.under_user_id;
 this.brought_by = binary.brought_by;
 this.username = binary.username;
 };
```

A method to get all binary for a user

```
Tree.findBinaries = async (id, result) => {
  const theId = parseInt(id);
  let transend = [theId];
  let step = 1;
  let data = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < step; i++) {
    const under = transend[i];
    connection.query(
      `SELECT * FROM multilevel WHERE under = ?`,
      under,
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          result(null, err);
          return;
        }
        if (res.length) {
          for (let index = 0; index < res.length; index++) {
            const { id } = res[index];
            // push id
            transend.push(id);
            data.push(res[index]);
            step = step * 2;
          }
          result(null, data);
        } else {
          result(null, "no data found");
        }
      }
    );
  }
};
```

The transend.push(id) and data.push(res[index]), are not been pushed to the top level, also the step is not been updated. So the loop is running just once.

The expected Result is supposed to be 16 items of children and children of children, But it is currently returning to just the first level. I don't know what I'm currently doing wrong.

Comment: Please, provide what is in `$memory`, and the `multilevel ` table data sample

Comment: @PauloFernando, $memory is the user's id and the multilevel table contents are:> id:1,position: "L", user_id: 2, brought_by: 1, under_user_id: 1, username: "user1"

Comment: Can you post a print screen of the PHP output and all the table that has the 16 itens?